# Jquery sorting table alphabetically by different columns based on class

Tags: jquery, sorting

I'm trying to sort a table based on either the text value in column 1 or column 0, subject to what class the row has.

The aim is to order the table A->Z but some rows I need to check a different column.

If the rows class is `classA` then use text from `column 1` if the rows class is `classB` then use the text from `column 0`

So far I've got this code and it works on column 1, but I'm not sure how to adapt this to work across columns 0 or 1

```
rows = $table.find('tr');
sortedRows = rows.sort( function (a, b) {
            
if ( $(a).find('td').eq(1).find("input").val() > $(b).find('td').eq(1).find("input").val() ) {
    return 1;
}
        
if ( $(a).find('td').eq(1).find("input").val() < $(b).find('td').eq(1).find("input").val() ) {
    return -1;
}
            
return 0;
})
```

Basically the table looks like this:

```
Column 0            Column 1
                    North
                    South
East        
                    West
Top
                    Bottom
```

When sorted it should look like this:

```
Column 0            Column 1
                    Bottom  
East        
                    North
                    South
Top
                    West
```

Anyone any ideas on this ?
Thanks

Comment: Are they both inputs? seems like you could just reference the input in the row.

Comment: They are both inputs, unfortunately they have multiple inputs in the row so I need to target specific columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So check for a class and use that to determine what index to check

```
function getValue (row) {
  var index = row.hasClass('classB') ? 0 : 1
  return row.find('td').eq(index).find("input").val() 
}

rows = $table.find('tr');
sortedRows = rows.sort( function (a, b) {
  return getValue($(a)).localeCompare($(b))
})
```

Comment: This `return row.find('td').eq(index).find("input").val() ` returns index not defined. Should that be col ? I then get `Cannot read property 'localeCompare' of undefined` any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: Thanks got this sorted with a slight change